# Is It Mandatory to Implement Apple Sign In Even Though the App Has Game Center Sign In

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, apple-sign-in, apple-developer

In my app I use Google Sign In and Game Center Sign In. My app rejected due to **Guideline 4.8 - Design - Sign in with Apple**. I already have Game Center sign in so do i still have to implement Apple Sign In? I asked to apple team about it they didn't give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is mandatory to implement Apple Sign-In because you have implemented a social sign-in (Google).

The only scenarios when you are allowed to skip Apple Sign-In, while providing a social sign-in are mentioned under guideline 4.8 ([link for reference](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple)).

Game-Center sign-in is not equivalent to Apple Sign-In and cannot take its place.